# Google Play Game Services messages never sent

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I've a problem with google play game services APIs. I correctly get the GoogleSignAccount. Then, I open a Room creating a RealtimeMultiplayerClient. When I  try to send anything in reliable mode, I'm not able to trace the message and the receiver listener is never called. I'm trying with just two players and I noticed that the roomId is different for them (in reality, it is in the form of XXX____YYY and the XXX string is the same for them). The code for sending message is the following:

```
private final RealTimeMultiplayerClient.ReliableMessageSentCallback mySentListener = new RealTimeMultiplayerClient.ReliableMessageSentCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onRealTimeMessageSent(int statusCode, int tokenId, String recipientParticipantId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "RealTime message sent");
        Log.d(TAG, "  statusCode: " + statusCode);
        Log.d(TAG, "  tokenId: " + tokenId);
        Log.d(TAG, "  recipientParticipantId: " + recipientParticipantId);
    }
};

public void sendReliable(final String playerId) {
    final Task<Integer> sendTask = GoogleRoom.getInstance().getRealTimeMultiplayerClient()
        .sendReliableMessage(buffer, GoogleRoom.mRoomId, playerId, mySentListener);
    sendTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failure " + e);
        }
    });
    sendTask.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Integer> task) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Completed");
        }
    });
    sendTask.addOnCanceledListener(new OnCanceledListener() {
           @Override
           public void onCanceled() {
               Log.d(TAG, "Canceled");
           }
    });
}
```

The strange thing is that no listener is called. Any suggest?

Comment: Anyway, it seems that the Google callback run on the main thread. Now it works and the problem should be that there was a loop until the message hasn't been received and in that way Google hadn't the chance to gain the control and invoke its methods...